# Chemfig superscript and \llap

Tags: chemfig

Does anyone have any idea how to avoid the overlap between the bond and the "12"?
Thanks!

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
   \chemfig{H-{\llap{${}^{12}$}C}(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H}
\end{document}
```

[image: Output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Should the number 12 be above the chemical bond or next to the carbon?
you can adjust the distance and angle by changing the parameters inside the \charge command (150 is the angle and 3pt is the distance between the carbon and the number 12)

```
\documentclass[border=2mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\begin{document}
    \chemfig{H-\charge{150:3pt=$\scriptstyle 12$}{C}(-[2]H)(-[6]H)-H}
\end{document}
```

[image]